# echo passed variable via class="" using document.write()

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

May I ask, why is it that this is not echoing any data? `<input>` receives a value of AAA-123-0001 by passing value in `class=""` (this is a modal:edit)

This line alone `<input type="text" class="decid" id="decid" name="decid">` is working and displays the data that is being passed into the input box, but when I try to echo it, it wont.

```
<input type="text" class="decid" id="decid" name="decid">
<script type="text/javascript">
var abc = document.getElementById("decid").value;
<?php $abc = "<script>document.write(abc)</script>"?>   
</script>
<?php echo $abc;?>
```

But, when I supply it with data directly via var, it echoes.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var abc = "echo value";
<?php $abc = "<script>document.write(abc)</script>"?>   
</script>
<?php echo $abc;?>
```

Also, when I try to feed the input box with data straight from `value=""`, it works.

```
<input type="text" class="feed" id="`feed" name="feed" value="feed">
<script type="text/javascript">
var abc = document.getElementById("feed").value;
<?php $abc = "<script>document.write(abc)</script>"?>   
</script>
<?php echo $abc;?>
```

The data is being passed through javascript

```
$(function(){
  $("body").on('click', '.edit', function (e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#edit').modal('show');
    var id = $(this).data('id');
    getRow(id);
  });
```

May I ask for a solution on this concern?

Comment: the `#decid` input doesn't have any value when the JavaScript `abc` variable is set.

Comment: @Titus is there a loop for this? an exploit perhaps? without using AJAX?

Comment: May I ask what you're trying to acheave with this?

Comment: Do you want to show the input's value below it ?

Comment: @GentleSama I'm planning to use ````$abc```` as an SQL parameter, I understand that doing this via ````<form>```` will be the most logical thing to do, but I'm at 50% with my project, and doing it all via form will cost me even more time.

Comment: @Titus, I want the data to be saved as an ````echo```` so that I can use it as an SQL parameter.

Comment: Oh, I see, in that case, you cannot do that, all the PHP code is executed on the server side to generate HTML, CSS and JavaScript which means that you cannot set a PHP variable (server side context) using JavaScript (client side context). You will need to send that info to the server somehow (AJAX, form submission).

Comment: I guess I really have no choice, thank you!